# @IBInspectable coming back nil in custom button class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ludovicjamet/how-to-use-storyboard-to-create-and-preview-custom-views-92acad7405fa) in order to create reusable UI components for interface builder. I have followed the article exactly and the results I'm getting are the same as explained in the article.

The issue I'm not having is that I have added an `@IBInspectable` property called style to the class, which shows up fine in the properties inspector of interface builder, however no matter what I do it always comes back nil in both the `Setup()` and `loadViewFromNib()` methods of the `MyButton` class.

Being new to Interface Builder custom components, I am starting to wonder whether the method followed in the article breaks @IBInspectable properties, as I have used them successfully past by using custom UIButton classes without adding the extra XIB component.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    @IBDesignable
    class MyButton: UIButton {
        @IBOutlet weak var view: UIButton!
        @IBInspectable var style: String!
...
```

Comment: I have the same problem ? Did you found a solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are never initializing the variable with a default value.

Try setting it equal to an empty string and removing the explicit unwrap like this:

`@IBInspectable var style: String = ""`